Help me identify old movie with dream scene of blonde boys (mutliples of same kid) chasing grown man up a tree, and cutting it down
The movie may have been black and white, or perhaps we just saw it on a black and white TV. I'm guessing it was a 60s movie, as I would have seen it then as a small child. possibly 50s, released in the U.S. The plot had to do with a grown man (the main character), and there was a blonde curly haired boy who was naughty who it seemed was being thrust somehow into the man's life. I guess the boy terrorized the man. The man dreams he is being chased outdoors by several "clones" of the same kid. At one point they are all running downhill toward the camera. He climbs a tree to get away from them, but they begin hacking at it with hatchets. Fire may also have been set to the tree. 
This was not Dennis the Menace... the hair is much curlier, more like Will Farrell curly. I had nightmares of the vivid chase scene for years, and while it was a scary scene for me, I'm guessing now that what felt like a thriller to a kid is probably either a comedy, or at most a drama. Does anyone remember a movie scene were about a dozen "versions" of the same blonde little boy chase a man through the woods? While I'm fairly sure it was a movie, it is possible it was actually a TV show.
It is also possible that the boy (boys) was dressed in native American indian dress during chase in the the dream scene. Emphasizing that this was also likely a comedy, and not a horror movie, certainly with now paranormal activity like Village of the Damned. The boy didn't have any powers, such as hypnotic eyes, but was just mischievous

Welcome to the community. You have a lot of good information. But are there any other plot details you can think of?  I hope you enjoy this place as much as I have.

Hi John, thanks for the note. I'm really trying to remember some additional details. It was almost half a century ago that I saw this, lol... but it is probable that the man was in a relationship with the boy's mother. That's what I really don't remember-- it wasn't his son, so was it a neighbor or a son of his "interest". After hrs of looking on IMDB without luck, I found this site. I hope to remember more details so I can add.

I am seeking more details to add. Please give me some more time...

The one detail that I'm not positive about, but I think I recall it's possible that the boy (boys) was dressed in native American indian dress during chase in the the dream scene.

@Jan, thanks for the suggestion. I looked up that movie and also Children of the damned on a few sites. The reason that I think it could not be it is that my family members would have never let me watch, or would have watched themselves, anything with paranormal activity like that. My first thought though when I saw your suggestion was THAT would explain the nightmares. The boy's eyes were not hypnotic, in the movie I'm remembering. He didn't have powers, but was just mischievous.
